# VB6 IE frame / WebBrowser causing NT.dll error

Tags: vb6, browser, ieframe.dll

We have a legacy VB6 application which has worked just fine on Windows XP Professional SP 3 until just recently when we added an IE frame control so that we could display static local HTML files on a form.  And, it works fine until I go to close the application.  And, then it reports the following error message (consistently):

> Faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.5755, stamp 49901d48

Here's the reference in the Visual Basic project file:

> Object={EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}#1.1#0; ieframe.dll

And we use it by performing the following actions:

1. Development machine is running Win7 + Vb6 IDE.
2. Add a component reference to the "Microsoft Internet Controls" located at C:\Windows\SysWow64\ieframe.dll
3. Place a control on the form at design time.
4. Show that form modally by calling

   ```
   Form.Show vbModal
   ```

   The error happens when I use the default form instance

   ```
   frmMyForm.Show vbModal
   ```

   as well as when I use a local instance

   ```
   Dim MyForm as New frmMyForm
   MyForm.Show vbModal
   ```
5. Call WebBrowser.Navigate "staticPage.html"
6. When the user presses a button, the button click event returns the user choice and the form is disposed of.

   Exit the application -- Here's where I get the error.

I've been looking all over the web, and haven't been able to find a whole lot of people still trying to use VB6 in this way.  So, I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me on stackoverflow.  Any help is much appreciated!

[Update]  And, the plot thickens.  I made a sample application with just that web component in order to make sure that it was causing the error.  But, I didn’t experience the error when it closed like I was when exiting our existing/legacy vb6 application.  I'll do a bit more investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A follow up to this in case any runs into the same issue (the original poster and I were coworkers at the time)...

The application was using the [VBCorLib](http://www.kellyethridge.com/vbcorlib/) library, and some of its string manipulation classes utilized direct memory access incorrectly. Read more at [this VBCorLib forum post](http://killian35.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=Help&action=display&thread=98&page=1).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was that I was trying to delete the temporary file that the browser had loaded.  It works now that I've moved that delete file code to the form unload event.